# Looping Over And Array of Objects and Updating Each One

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update objects inside an array based on specific conditions that I check using two functions. I couldn't achieve this with the `match` feature available in `mongoose`.

As you can see below, I'm trying to loop over the array of posts, send each post and check if it fulfills a condition, then update it using `findOneAndUpdate`. The functions `isLessThanOne` and `isAchieved` return the expected value.

```
(async () => {

  let posts = await Post.find()

  posts.map(async (post) => {
    if (isLessThanOneDay(post.deadline)) {
      console.log(post.id, post._id)
      await Post.findOneAndUpdate(post.id, { $set: { category: 'deadline' }})
    } else if (isAchieved(post.milestones)) {
      await Post.findOneAndUpdate(post.id, { $set: { category: 'achieved' }})
    } else {
      await Post.findOneAndUpdate(post.id, { $set: { category: 'newGoals' }})
    }
  })
  
})()
```

This is the `schema`

```
const { type } = require("express/lib/response")
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    // we have to link or refer each post to a user
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "user",
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    desc: {
        type: String
    },
    milestones: [],
    likes: [
        {
            user: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: "user"
            },
            fName: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            date: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            }

        }
    ],
    comments: [
        {
            user: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: "user"
            },
            text: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            fName: {
                type: String,
            },
            date: {
                type: String,
            }
        }
    ],
    rewards: [
        {
            user: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: "user"
            },
            fName: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            date: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            reward: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            price: {
                type: Number,
                required: true
            }
        }
    ],
    date: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    shares: [
        {
            user: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: "user"
            },
            fName: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            date: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            }

        }
    ],
    deadline: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    category: {
        type: String,
    }


}) 

module.exports = Post = mongoose.model('post', PostSchema)
```

The problem is that I couldn't update the posts and I've already tried using `udpate`, directly updating it with `post.category` then `save`. Any help would appreciated.

Comment: What is the difference between post.id and post._id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
(async () => {

  let posts = await Post.find()

  posts.map(async (post) => {
    if (isLessThanOneDay(post.deadline)) {
      console.log(post.id, post._id)
      await Post.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: post.id }, { $set: { category: 'deadline' }})
    } else if (isAchieved(post.milestones)) {
      await Post.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: post.id }, { $set: { category: 'achieved' }})
    } else {
      await Post.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: post.id }, { $set: { category: 'newGoals' }})
    }
  })
  
})()
```

If I recall, the filter parameter must be an object.